# Tenured or Old Gen Memory spikes using V2 AWS DynamoDB SDK in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, memory-leaks, amazon-dynamodb

We have a springboot application talking to a DynamoDB table which uses the V2 AWS SDK with DynamoDBEnhancedClient. On deploying the application to EKS and running a load test, we saw an issue where the application was consuming a lot of memory as expected due to high volume of requests. [image]

However, after the load test stopped at 1:09 in the graph below, we expected the memory to be claimed and recovered but instead it remained flatline pegged at high even with no more incoming requests.

[image]

This is how the application is wired up.

We have the configuration class where DynamoDB client BEAN is instantiated.

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public class DynamoConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Profile({"!local & !integrationtest"})
    public DynamoDbClient getDynamoDbClient() {
        return DynamoDbClient.builder()
            .region(Region.of(System.getenv("AWS_REGION")))
            .credentialsProvider(WebIdentityTokenFileCredentialsProvider.builder().build()).build();
    }
    
    /**
     * Instantiates an enhanced DynamoDB client for interacting with DynamoDB.
     */
    @Bean
    public DynamoDbEnhancedClient getDynamoDbEnhancedClient(DynamoDbClient dynamoDbClient) 
    {
        return DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder()
            .dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient)
            .build();
    }
}
```

Next we have a repository class for the Student table with the client used to generated a table object first and all CRUD operations performed on the table.

NOTE: Load test was heavy on the findById function and not on the save function so it was read heavy.

```
@Repository
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class StudentRepository {

    private final DynamoDbEnhancedClient dynamoDbEnhancedClient;
    
    @Value("${dynamodb.tables.student}")
    private String studentTableName;

    /**
     * Retrieves a student by id.
     */
    public Optional<Student> findById(final String id) {
        DynamoDbTable<Student> studentTable = getTable();
        Key idKey = Key.builder().partitionValue(id).build();
        return Optional.ofNullable(studentTable.getItem(idKey));
    }

    /**
     * Saves a student to the table.
     */
    public void save(final Student Student) {
        DynamoDbTable<Student> studentTable = getTable();
        studentTable.putItem(Student);
    }
    
    /**
     * Gets Student table object.
     */
    private DynamoDbTable<Student> getTable() {
        return dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table(studentTableName, TableSchema.fromBean(Student.class));
    }
}
```

Any guidance on anything we are doing wrong in this setup especially with usage of @Bean and @Repository annotations? Or anything we need to do to terminate the DB connection or table object to ensure memory after the request is reclaimed?

Or do we need to try using the EnhancedAsync client if its a threading issue with the blocking client?

Open to any other suggestion since the SDK V2 is fairly new and not all issues have been documented.

This is the POM version of the SDK: 2.19.18 and the two libraries we are using.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>dynamodb-enhanced</artifactId>
    <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
    <artifactId>sts</artifactId>
    <version>${aws.java.sdk.version}</version>
</dependency>
<aws.java.sdk.version>2.19.18</aws.java.sdk.version>
```

Update:
HeapDump of dominators by retained:
[image]

Heapdump of objects by retained:
[image]

Comment: Without any heap dump etc... it's hard to tell. But from the information provided, the fact that you create the Table component for every request, which initiates a client would lead me to believe you create too many clients without closing any. Try a test where you only initiate the Table client once and share it across function invocations.

Comment: So instead of this line being called for every request, I will create an object from it and keep it in the repository class? I can test that out. Any suggestions for a heap dump on a docker container? 

return dynamoDbEnhancedClient.table(studentTableName, TableSchema.fromBean(Student.class));

Comment: Yea returning the entire Table object from the initialiser would be better IMO. As for heap dump, I'm no expert on docket so hopefully someone else can chime in and help you there. Let me know how the test goes.

Comment: It looks to me like your memory usage returned to the ~60% that it was using prior to the load test. And during the load test, it remained at a plateau. If you had an actual leak, I would have expected it to keep going up when under load, until you got an OOM.

Comment: It is also entirely possible that some objects moved into the tenured generation during the load test, and the JVM hasn't run a full collection since the test ended.

Comment: Uploaded a heapdump by objects as well as dominators.